# Pip install from zip file on private server not installing requirements and when requirements met it does not find the package

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I made a command line tool to manage some actions on the server-side, and I want to easily distribute it for my coworkers using `pip install` from a private server we have for internal tools, and to provide them with updates on it, so we don't have to walk around with a thumbstick and doing boring `pip install . -r requirements.txt` for every workstation they have.

I'd try to keep this short, but I think I have to include the project and packaging details to find the problem. I suspect a bad configuration of the `setup.py` file.

### The server

It is a simple NGINX pointing to a folder with basic auth `.htpass`. Inside the folder I have the zipped project (maybe this is my first mistake?).

To download and install using `pip` (Python 3.5+), I simply run

```bash
pip install http://username:password@pip.myserver.io/tools/mypackage.zip
```

### The `setup.py`

The requirements in the `setup.py` below are not downloaded.

```py
import os
from setuptools import setup
from mypackage import __version__, project_name


# Utility function to read the README file.
# Used for the long_description.  It's nice, because now 1) we have a top level
# README file and 2) it's easier to type in the README file than to put a raw
# string in below ...
def read(fname):
    return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()

setup(
  name=project_name,
  version=__version__,
  description='Command line client for maintenance and odd jobs on the server',
  long_description=read('README.md'),
  classifiers=[
        "Development Status :: 2 - Alpha",
        "Topic :: Utilities :: Rest",
        "Framework :: Click",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5",
  ],
  keywords='cli rest client admin',
  author="Myself",
  author_email='lucas@email.com',
  packages=['mypackage'],
  zip_safe=True,
  install_requires=[
      'certifi==2017.7.27.1',
      'chardet==3.0.4',
      'click==6.7',
      'idna==2.6',
      'requests==2.18.4',
      'urllib3==1.22',
      'terminaltables==3.1.0',
      'tqdm==4.19.4',
      'aiohttp==2.3.3',
      'aiodns==1.1.1',
      'cchardet==2.1.1',
      'async-timeout==2.0.0',
  ],
  entry_points='''
    [console_scripts]
        stp = mypackage.MyPackage:cli
        stp-config = mypackage.MyPackage:config
        ''',
  )
```

It tries to download the zip file and the `setup.py` marks the zip "safe" (I believe this might be my first mistake, but I can't test it atm), but it does not install the requirements.

The zip file has also the `EGG` folder of the installed package. I tried removing it *or* leaving it. Neither makes a difference whatsoever for the download/install. It still breaks because it lacks the dependencies.

If I install the requirements separately, I can install `myPackage` using `pip` (finally!) but when I try to call it by its entry point

```
stp --help
```

I receive an error saying that 'mypackage is not present'.

```
C:\Users\Scoppio>stp --help
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Scoppio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\stp-script.py", line 11, in <module>
load_entry_point('MyPackage==0.2.1', 'console_scripts', 'stp')()
File "c:\users\scoppio\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 565, in load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
File "c:\users\scoppio\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2631, in load_entry_point
return ep.load()
File "c:\users\scoppio\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2291, in load
return self.resolve()
File "c:\users\scoppio\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2297, in resolve
module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
File "c:\users\scoppio\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\mypackage\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from mypackage.my_client import myUrls
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mypackage.my_client '
```

You may notice that this error message is from a Windows OS, but I get analogous errors on Mac OSX and Ubuntu 16.

And if I go to the folder which should have installed it inside the site-packages and open it, my package 'mypackage' has only the files there where inside the first folder level, for no apparent reason it discarded all the upper folders I had in place for the project.

### The file structure

So my project structure was:

```
core/
    setup.py
    requirements.txt
    readme.md
    mypackage/
       __init__.py
       context.py
       my_package.py
       my_client/
          __init__.py
          rest_client.py
          my_urls.py
       my_plugins/
          __init__.py
          cmd_1.py
          cmd_2.py
          ...
          cmd_n.py
          utils/
             __init__.py
             print_table.py
```

but after installation with `pip`, I am left with just those files

```
mypackage/
   __init__.py
   context.py
   my_package.py
```

I explored the temporary file `pip` makes, but the whole project is present there, it simply does not install all the files I need.

So far I only managed to install everything by manually adding the files missing, but it moots the point of using pip to install the project.

I believe that I misunderstood the `setuptools` documentation and now I am tracing a few possible approaches, like adding more packages to the package entry in the setup, and using "extra" requirements instead of requirements.

Comment: As for missing files after installation, the solution is easy - `packages=find_packages()` should include all the submodules recursively. Import it as usual, `from setuptools import find_packages`. Do you use `setuptools` or plain `distutils`? AFAIK, `distutils` does not understand the keyword `install_requires` at all. Also, you have `requirements.txt` and `install_requires` keyword set - which one contains the dependencies you want to install?

Comment: Looking trough the Click "setuptools integration" i found that I was missing the find_packages (and another one entry, I'll rectify it tomorrow here).
Also, the requirements and the install_requires are exact copies from one another. I believe that I am using setuptools, because this is what I am importing and all.

Comment: Ok, so the mystery of the missing packages is solved. About the dependencies that aren't installed - if you download the zip and install it from the local fs (`pip install Downloads/mypackage-0.2.1.zip`), will the deps install then? If not, I should be able to reproduce the issue using the setup script you provided.

Comment: No, when I install from local, even if the project is unziped, it does not install the requirements. I have to run pip install -r req... before running pip install . , later today i'll give some more attention to it and try to solve the error. From what I see you should be able to create a mock project and run the setup.py and get exactly the same error I have, if you do not have an error it would be very interesting to compare the steps that we made and how they differ. Thanks!

Comment: I created a fresh venv (`python3.6`), copied your `setup.py` over, added stub for `README.md`, added stub for `mypackage` with `__init__.py` containing two lines for `__version__` and `project_name`, added stub click commands for `entry_points` and replaced `packages` list with `find_packages()`, built the package with `python setup.py sdist --formats=zip`, switched to a fresh venv, installed the package with `pip install dist/spam-0.1.zip`. The dependencies are installed as expected.

Comment: My suspect is that you have some package leftovers (like `.pth` files or smth else) that mislead `pip` into thinking the packages are already installed. To be sure nothing stands in the way, I would create and activate a fresh venv, switch to a fresh dir (`/tmp` would be good), download the zip file to it with `wget` or `curl` and install it with `pip install -vvv mypackage.zip`. Then check the beginning of the installation log, the downloading of dependencies should be right at the start, when the `egg_info` command is executed.

Comment: So I added the find_packages with no success... I think illhave to cut it into many small and separated projects to make ut work properly @_@ the installation ill try later today on a virtual env

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after some headache I've found what I was doing wrong.

First of all I was importing data from my main package (from **init**.py of my_package) an there where some unused imports that were hidden/greyed out by PyCharm, those imports had files that imported not installed packages, which was the reason why it was not allowing the installation to run (if the requirements.txt were run before, then the imports would not matter), the whole setup.py was not working thanks to my imports that were left there.

The setup.py now have the following entries diff from original:

```
packages=find_packages(),
include_package_data=True,
zip_safe=False,
```

working just fine :D